# Installing a shared framework with multiple apps in the same bundle

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

This is more of an installation strategy question.

Our company has about half a dozen applications. We wish to have a single custom installer for all of those applications, since most customers install more than one of our apps at a time (think Microsoft Office or Visual Studio as an analogy).

With separate per-user MSIs and a custom managed bootstrapper, this all works great.

Here’s the rub:

All of our apps are built on a common framework of managed and native DLLs that represent the large majority of the binary size for each of the apps. We don’t want to include those dependencies into each MSI separately, since the bundle compression is not doing a good job of keeping the installer size manageable. We'd also like the dependencies to be installed within each app directory to better enable side-by-side and to avoid both elevation (in case of GACing) or environment issues (in the case of messing with the PATH).

What is the best strategy for this? Should there be a separate MSI for the common framework? If so, should we have the bundle install it multiple times with different target paths? That seems like a bad idea.